# Is it possible to deprecate some of the values of a Java enum and if so, how?

Tags: java, enums, deprecated

I want to deprecate some, but not all possible *enumeration* values.

Comment: See [Annotations tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html).

Comment: I think it is about time to accept an answer here, I really doubt that much else will be showing up here ;-)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, put a @Deprecated annotation on them. For example:

```
enum Status {
    OK,
    ERROR,

    @Deprecated
    PROBLEM
}
```

You can also add a JavaDoc `@deprecated` tag to document it:

```
enum Status {
    OK,
    ERROR,

    /**
     * @deprecated Use ERROR instead.
     */
    @Deprecated
    PROBLEM
}
```

Comment: I've always (well, occasionally) wondered why the `@Deprecated` annotation type doesn't allow a `value` for that purpose.

Comment: "Don't use this value" is a useless comment. It doesn't say anything other than the deprecated annotation. A deprecation comment should tell by what the value is replaced.

Comment: @JB Nizet this was ofcourse only to demonstrate the principle. I changed it.

Comment: Yes, I have never used annotations much.  I am more familiar with deprecation via comments.  the @Deprecated solution is just what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 65):

```
public enum Characters {
    STAN,
    KYLE,
    CARTMAN,
    @Deprecated KENNY
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! THEY DEPRECATED KENNY!

Comment: I would change it to `@Deprecated(forRemoval=true) KENNY` for Java >=9 :-D.

Answer (score 6):

Just tried it eclipse, it works:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        System.err.println(EnumTest.A);
        System.err.println(EnumTest.B);

    }

    public static enum EnumTest {
        A, @Deprecated B, C, D, E;
    }

}
```